# Printing .py file output in command line

Tags: python, command-line, terminal

I am trying to access a python function from the command line, and I would like to write such a command that will print the output in the terminal. The below doesn't work. What could I change?

```
python -c 'from laser import Laser; laser = Laser();l = laser.embed_sentences("hello", lang = "en").shape == (1, 1024); print(l)'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(base) ~ % python -c 'print("hello, world")'
hello, world
```

Printing works fine for me when running python through `python -c`. Are you sure your terminal isn't truncating your output by omitting the last (and in this case, only) line? You could try creating a single line file (no newline at the end) and then running `cat [filename]` (which is how I sometimes discover that my terminal is doing this)

Answer (score 0):

`-c cmd : program passed in as string (terminates option list)`

That is the correct flag to be used. This must be a CLI config issue. Or the script is taking longer than you are expecting to run and it appears no output is generated.

Does `python -c 'print("hello")'` work?